# depmod -a cannot generate modules.dep

Tags: linux, driver

When I compiled a driver module and `insmod` failed, I used `modinfo` to check and found that `modules.dep` was missing. After checking the data, it was said that `depmod -a` could be generated, but I tried and did not generate it. I don't know the reason?

```
root@dobot:/lib/modules/6.4.0-rt8# insmod f81604.ko
insmod: can't insert 'f81604.ko': unknown symbol in module or invalid parameter
root@dobot:/lib/modules/6.4.0-rt8#
root@dobot:/lib/modules/6.4.0-rt8# modinfo f81604.ko
modinfo: can't open '/lib/modules/6.4.0-rt8/modules.dep': No such file or directory
root@dobot:/lib/modules/6.4.0-rt8#
root@dobot:/lib/modules/6.4.0-rt8# depmod -a
root@dobot:/lib/modules/6.4.0-rt8#
root@dobot:/lib/modules/6.4.0-rt8# ls
dca.ko           f81604.ko        i2c-algo-bit.ko  igb.ko           modules.dep.bb   pps_core.ko      ptp.ko
```